# TypeError: $(...).removeBlockMessages is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, commonjs

I have the following code on update.phtml:

```
$(function(){
$('#editUser').submit(function(event)
{
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');
    // Stop full page load
    event.preventDefault();

    //Request
    var data = {
        // user's properties 
        genderUser              :       $("#genderUser").val(),
        lastnameUser            :       $("#lastnameUser").val(),
        firstnameUser           :       $("#firstnameUser").val(),
        emailUser               :       $("#emailUser").val(),
        passwordUser            :       $("#passwordUser").val(),
        confirmPasswordUser     :       $("#confirmPasswordUser").val(),
        isActiveUser            :       $("input[name='isActiveUser']").val(),
        langUser                :       $("select[name='langUser']").val(),
        rankUser                :       $("#rankUser").val()
    };  

    // Send
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#'+formId).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {                    
            if (data.response == true)
            {
                $('#edit-block').removeBlockMessages().blockMessage(data.message, {type: 'success'});
                upContent('user/index/','');



            }
```

on my controller :

```
if($user->editUser($data))
{
    echo json_encode(array(
                        "response"  =>  true,
                        "message"   =>  "L'utilisateur " . $data['lastnameUser'] . " " . $data['firstnameUser'] . "a été modifié"
                    ));
    exit();
```

When I click on update I have this error :

> TypeError: $(...).removeBlockMessages is not a function

Comment: Have you included the library for the respective function plugins?

Comment: when can i include the library because i do that on Layout <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$this->baseUrl('resources_bo/js/common.js');?>"></script> but always i have this error TypeError: $(...).removeBlockMessages is not a function

Comment: Seems like removeBlockMessages couldn't be found.

Comment: how can i resolved this issue thanks for help

Comment: Have you checked that removeBlockMessages() is a function in your commonjs-version?

Comment: yes  exist in commonjs